# Arraylist Difficulties

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a complicated computer science lab. I need to create a method called countItem which returns the quantity of a specified item.  If the item is not in the list, it should return 0. Cart is an arraylist of Items. Getquantity returns the quantity which is a instance field of the item file.

After building I get two unexpected type errors. Can anyone help me fix this problem? I can post more code if needed. Thanks

EDIt: THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED THANKS SO MUCH!

```
public int countItem(Item purchase)
     {
        int purchase = 0;
        if(cart.indexOf(purchase) == -1) // error
            quantity = 0;
        else
            purchase.getQuantity() = quantity; //error

        return quantity;
      }

 public boolean removeItem(Item nameofitem)
     {

        boolean search;

        if(cart.indexOf(nameofitem) == -1)
            return search;
        else
            {
                cart.remove(cart.indexOf(nameofitem));
                search = true;
            }

        return search;
     }
```

Comment: 'unexpected type errors' - What's the exact error message? That probably already answers half your question.

Comment: It also looks like quantity is a local variable, so you need to declare it somewhere, `int quantity;` (you may have declared purchase twice above, I assume that `int purchase = 0` should be quantity

Answer (score 3):

Equality checking is done with `==`.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, its getting late and I'm extremely tired. Thanks!

Comment: If your question is answered, feel free to mark the question as answered (by clicking on the 'tick' on the left hand side of my answer).

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the assignment operator, you need  two equals signs, `==` for comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

For your second problem, I think you need:

```
purchase.setQuantity(quantity);
```